# Application stops working when fragment swap - Java Android

Tags: java, android, androidx

I am trying to place **fragments** in my app, it works normal even, but when switching screens through **BottomNavigationView**, the app stops **running**

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData;

I've tried putting different implementations of Lifecycle but it doesn't help at all

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*************"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0-rc04"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
  implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
  implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
  implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:+'
  compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
}

--------------
Fragment used
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class Lessons extends Fragment
{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lessons_fragment, container, false);
        return inflate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the android lifecycle dependency to make use of LiveData.

See the following page for details: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle

For the current version add the following to your dependencies:

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.1.0"

// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
```

If you didn't actually use any LiveData components, posting the full stacktrace would be more useful.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace? @user9708148

Comment: How to post stracktrace?